# Setting up flash music player as opengraph tag

Tags: flash, facebook-opengraph

I have a flash music player at http://www.etiennechampollion.com/lecteur/compositions.htm
with a Facebook like button.

I've set OpenGraph meta tags in order to specify the url of the flash
object :

```
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-
flash" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.etiennechampollion.com/
lecteur/dewplayer-
playlist.swf&showtime=true&autostart=true&autoreplay=true&xml=http://
www.etiennechampollion.com/lecteur/compositions.xml">
```

If you try to play directly
http://www.etiennechampollion.com/lecteur/dewplayer-playlist.swf?showtime=true&autostart=true&autoreplay=true&xml=http://www.etiennechampollion.com/lecteur/compositions.xml
in your browser, it works.

But, if one user clicks on the like button in order to share it on his
wall, the player will show, but with "XML error", which let me know
that it doesn't find the compositions.xml file.

In facebook, if I look at the source code of the page, I find that
facebook use a relative path : "compositions.xml".

So the question is : how could I do to allow Facebook to get the
player and the playlist via OpenGraph ?

Thank you for your help.

Arnaud

Answer (score 0):

You can use facebook debugger to fix the errors on the page: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug